# How to customize traditional form for inactive functions?

Tags: formatting, hold, traditional-form

Let's say I define

```
Lg[n_]:=Log[2,n].
```

How do I make

```
Inactive[Lg][x]//TraditionalForm
```

output

```
lg(x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions @ Inactive `` one can gather that it is `NumericFunction` attribute which enables `()` in `TraditionalForm`, as opposed to `[]`.

So if you don't mind we can set them. And one thing that is left is to change `Lg` to lowercase during typesetting:

```
ClearAll[Lg];

Lg[n_] := Log[2, n];

SetAttributes[Lg, NumericFunction];
Lg /: MakeBoxes[Lg, TraditionalForm] := "lg"

Inactive[Lg][x] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In general I would definitely prefer @Kuba's solution, but in case you can't add the `NumericFunction` attribute for some reason and you still want `(…)` instead of `[…]`, or if you want more control in general, you can do something like the following:

```
Unprotect@Inactive
Inactive /: MakeBoxes[Inactive[Lg][n_], TraditionalForm] := 
 RowBox@{"ln", "(", MakeBoxes[n, TraditionalForm], ")"}
Protect@Inactive
```

Of course, this simple formatting rule does not show the `"Inactive[…]"` tooltip that is normally added (if you want it, just adapt the above rule)

**Important**: Be sure to evaluate this before anything else relating to `Inactive`, otherwise it won't work.

#### Why does it not work otherwise?

The issue is that `Inactive` expressions are formatted via upvalues (or apparently `FormatValues` to be more precise) of `Inactive`. This means that you cannot attach the rule to `MakeBoxes` or `Format` as you would normally, as these are applied too late in the process. And to make sure that your definition is evaluated before any of the other definitions, you have to make your definition before any of the others are loaded.